# Large scale triangular least squares

Tags: linear-solver, sparse-matrix, least-squares

I have to solve the following least squares problem:
\begin{equation}
\| \left[ \begin{smallmatrix} \mathbf{L} \\ \mathbf{I} \end{smallmatrix} \right]\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{b} \|_2^2
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{L} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is $O(n)$ sparse lower triangular matrix, $\mathbf{I} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is the identity and $\mathbf{b} = \left[ \begin{smallmatrix} \mathbf{b}_1 \\ \mathbf{b}_2 \end{smallmatrix} \right] \in \mathbb{R}^{2n}$.

Hence, solving individual system $\mathbf{Lx} = \mathbf{b}_1$ is of $O(n)$ complexity, by the forward substitution algorithm, but the least squares fit is expensive.

I am open to *any* suggestion, including fast approximate stochastic solvers etc. Of course, it would be perfect if one is aware of a direct method that exploits this kind of structure.

Comment: The normal equation is like $(L^tL + I)x = L^tb_1 + b_2$. If the conditioning is not too bad, maybe you can try to solve it with conjugate gradient, this just requires a function to compute $y = (L^tL + I)x$, which can be decomposed in $y_1 = Lx; y= L^t y_1 + x$ if you want to avoid assembling $L^tL$. You may also want to compute $Diag(L^tL + I)$ for preconditioning it with Jacobi.

Comment: The problem is that $\mathbf{L}$ comes from discretization of a PDE, so it is (increasingly) ill-conditioned. Forming the normal equations would square the condition number, of course.

Shortly, we tried CG with different preconditioners, and it does work up to some scale. I was hoping more for a method that scales linearly with dimension (_e.g._ algebraic multigrid - like).

Answer (score 4):

This looks isomorphic to [Tikhonov regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization) (a.k.a. ridge regression).  Some googling brought up [LSQR](http://web.stanford.edu/group/SOL/software/lsqr/) and the newer [LSMR](http://web.stanford.edu/group/SOL/software/lsmr/).  Those links both have implementations in a number of languages.  For large scale problems, Petsc has [KSPLSQR](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/KSP/KSPLSQR.html) built in.

Depending on what you mean by 'large scale', mlpack may also work.  Mlpack has a [tutorial](http://www.mlpack.org/docs/mlpack-1.0.12/doxygen.php?doc=lrtutorial.html) covering both its command line program as well as its C++ api.

Comment: Indeed, it is in a way Tikhonov regularization, and we are actually using LSMR right now, to avoid building the normal equations. By "large scale" I mean "potentially huge scale" (right now, about $O(10^7)$, but this is actually quite modest).